# ¿Cómo romper un bucle de un método de manera externa?

Tags: java, eclipse, timeout

Estoy trabajando en una carga de datos masiva, que puede tardar varios minutos en hacerse, pero necesito que si el tiempo de esa carga supera los 10 minutos, salte una excepción mediante un timeout.

Actualmente tengo lo siguiente:

```
    private Future<Boolean> ejecutando = null;

    public void cargaMasiva(){
        boolean haFinalizadoBien = false;
            
        try {
            haFinalizadoBien = realizarCarga().get(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            ejecutando = new AsyncResult<Boolean>(haFinalizadoBien);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ejecutando = new AsyncResult<Boolean>(false);
            ejecutando.cancel(true);
            log.info("Se ha parado la carga masiva por rebasar el tiempo permitido");
        }
    }
```

El método al que llama es el siguiente:

```
@Asynchronous
public Future<Boolean> realizarCarga(){

    boolean cargaRealizada = false;

    // Bucle que simula el método de carga
    while(condicion) {
        log.info("Proceso de carga ejecutandose");
    };

    cargaRealizada = true;

    return new AsyncResult<Boolean>(cargaRealizada);

}
```

Teniendo en cuenta estos dos métodos y tal cual están planteados, el timeout sí que me salta, pero a pesar de ello, el bucle se sigue ejecutando. Lo que necesito es que ese bucle se rompa de alguna manera al saltar el timeout.

Comment: as intentado usar `break;`

Comment: Lo que quiero es que el bucle se pare cuando salta el timeout de fuera del método. No poner un ```break``` en el bucle.

Comment: Necesitas implementar un cancelationtoken y verificarlo en todas las vueltas...